# iOS - UISearchBar with UIButton in RigthView and the default clear button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, uisearchbar

I'm trying to add a UIButton to the right side of a UISearchBar, and the text should stop before the UIButton, like this

| TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText | UIButton | x |

I have made some attempts, but without success.

The first approach I made was accessing the UITextField of the UISearchBar, and set the UIButton as the RightView of the UITextField. This worked but the clear button was hidden.

The second approach I tried was a SubClass of UITextField. I have overridden the method `(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds` to add some right padding, and I added the button like a subview of the UISearchBar. This would work, but since I'm using UISearchBar, I think I can't use a custom class of UITextField.

I'm out of ideas, do you know how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @Koen No, not yet :/